# Dynamically Reading COBOL Redefines with C#

Tags: c#, cobol, mainframe, ebcdic

I'm making a C# program that will be able to dynamically read an IBM HOST Copybook written in COBOL and generate an SQL table off of it. Once the table is generated I can upload a file into my program and it will read, convert from IMB-37 and insert the file into that sql table. So far I can handle almost anything, although I'm running into some issues with REDEFINES.

For example:

```
           10   SOME-FIELD        PIC 9(3)      COMP-3.     SCRRB205
4117       10   SOME-OTHER-FIELD REDEFINES                  3041-17
4117              SOME-FIELD      PIC X(2).                 3041-17
```

I understand that the redefine takes the place of the field above it in this case, although what i don't understand is how the compiler knows if it should use the redefine on it or not. I'm assuming that in this case it will be because the first one is a number where the second one is a character, although in the example below they are all using characters.

```
 05  STREET-ADDRESS.
       10  ADDRESS-LINE-1               PIC X(20).
       10  ADDRESS-LINE-2               PIC X(20).
   05  PO-BOX REDEFINES STREET-ADDRESS  PIC X(40).
```

I have tried just ignoring the redefines since it will always take the same amount of space, but in the case where the original field is packed and the redefined one is not I need to know when to unpack the field.

Any help with this would be amazing guys!

Comment: This is a design issue more than a coding issue.  I think you would want to store these using one of the original definition and ignore the redefine.  However, you would want to save the information about the redefine so that you know how to handle it in your code.  Of course, I am guessing that you are converting from COBOL to C#/SQL Server.

Comment: Yes i am converting the COBOL to SQL. I was thinking about just storing the information in the original definition, but the problem is that when i convert the EBCDIC text (downloaded from the mainframe) into ASCII i need to know which redefine it uses because i need to know if i have to unpack the text or not.

Comment: It has been a long time since I thought in COBOL, but I think that if you take the first definition for the database, then the redefines would be handled in the application if needed.  For example, you would store Address-Line-1, Address-Line-2 as the lowest level of detail and then create PO-BOX if necessary in your C# code, but you would probably just do it differently.  Meaning, you would not need to have a data variable called PO-BOX.

Comment: Similarly in your first example, you would store the SOME-FIELD        PIC 9(3) as the correct database detail and then if absolutely necessary you would convert the int to a string in your C# code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can maybe help you, as 2 years ago I have accomplished exactly what you are doing now.

I had to design a MySQL Datawarehouse, including the ETL system, based exclusively on files from a **RM COBOL** ERP application running on Linux.
The application had more than 600 files, and it was still unclear how much of them would finally end up in the database. Most of the important files were indexed, on COMP fields to make it harder, and one of the obvious requirement was that all relationships between files and their indexed keys could be reproduced on the database. So I potentially needed every field of every file.

Giving the number of files, it was out of question to treat all the files, manually and one by one.

I saw only one pragmatic solution to my problem: applying [automatic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_programming). Ie coding a program that would generate programs, from only one source: the cobol copybooks.

I had some restrictions (set by the client) on the technology that I was allowed to use. I finally ended up with a VB.NET application that take the COBOL copybooks in input, and :

1. Generates COBOL programs that convert the data in something exploitable, by reading the original indexed files and writing the records in a sequential text file.
2. Generates VBA modules with all the code needed to import those data files from MS Access into MySQL (including CREATE TABLE and Indexes)

At the beginning of the project, I ran into exactly the same issues than you now, notably those damn REDEFINES. I found the task of listing and coding all copybook possibilities, if not impossible, at least hazardous. 
So I looked into another way, and found this :

### CB2XML

**COBOL copybook to XML converter**: [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cb2xml/)

This saved me weeks of hard work on copybook parsing and interpreting. 
It can parse COBOL copybooks to change them into an XML file describing perfectly all PICTURE with a lot of useful attributes, like *length* or *type*. It fully support COBOL'86 standards.

Example with an **Invoice** file ( *Facture* in french)

```
000001 FD  FACTURE.                                                     
000006 01  REC-FACTURE.                                                 
000011     03  FS1                  PIC X.                              
000016     03  FS2.                                                     
000021         05  FS2A            PIC 9.                               
               05  RFS2B           PIC X(8).
000026         05  FS2B REDEFINES RFS2B  PIC 9(8).
000031     03  FS3.                                                     
000036         05  FS3A            PIC 9.                               
000041         05  FS3B            PIC X(10).                            
000046     03  FS4.                                                     
000051         05  FS4A            PIC 99.                              
000056         05  FS4B            PIC 99.                              
000061         05  FS4C            PIC 99.                              
000066     03  FS5                 PIC X(5).                              
000071     03  FS6                 PIC X(20).                           
000076     03  FS7                 PIC 9.                               
000081     03  FS8                 PIC S9(9)V99    COMP-3.              
000086     03  FS9                 PIC S9(9)V99    COMP-3.              
000091     03  FS10                PIC 9.                               
000096     03  FS11                PIC S9(9)V99    COMP-3.              
000101     03  FS12                PIC S9(9)V99    COMP-3.              
000106     03  FS13                PIC S9(9)V99    COMP-3.              
000111     03  FS14-15 OCCURS 10.                                       
000116         05  FS14            PIC 9.                               
000121         05  FS15            PIC S9(9)V99    COMP-3.              
000126         05  FS16            PIC S9(9)V99    COMP-3.              
000131     03  FS17 OCCURS 10       PIC S9(9)V99    COMP-3.              
000136     03 FS18                 PIC 9(6).                            
000141     03  FS19                PIC 9.                               
000241     03  FILLER              PIC X.
```

Turns into this :

```xml
<copybook filename="FD8.COP.CLEAN">
    <item display-length="428" level="01" name="REC-FACTURE" position="1" storage-length="428">
        <item display-length="1" level="03" name="FS1" picture="X" position="1" storage-length="1"/>
        <item display-length="9" level="03" name="FS2" position="2" storage-length="9">
            <item display-length="1" level="05" name="FS2A" numeric="true" picture="9" position="2" storage-length="1"/>
            <item display-length="8" level="05" name="RFS2B" picture="X(8)" position="3" redefined="true" storage-length="8"/>
            <item display-length="8" level="05" name="FS2B" numeric="true" picture="9(8)" position="3" redefines="RFS2B" storage-length="8"/>
        </item>
        <item display-length="11" level="03" name="FS3" position="11" storage-length="11">
            <item display-length="1" level="05" name="FS3A" numeric="true" picture="9" position="11" storage-length="1"/>
            <item display-length="10" level="05" name="FS3B" picture="X(10)" position="12" storage-length="10"/>
        </item>
        <item display-length="6" level="03" name="FS4" position="22" storage-length="6">
            <item display-length="2" level="05" name="FS4A" numeric="true" picture="99" position="22" storage-length="2"/>
            <item display-length="2" level="05" name="FS4B" numeric="true" picture="99" position="24" storage-length="2"/>
            <item display-length="2" level="05" name="FS4C" numeric="true" picture="99" position="26" storage-length="2"/>
        </item>
        <item display-length="5" level="03" name="FS5" picture="X(5)" position="28" storage-length="5"/>
        <item display-length="20" level="03" name="FS6" picture="X(20)" position="33" storage-length="20"/>
        <item display-length="1" level="03" name="FS7" numeric="true" picture="9" position="53" storage-length="1"/>
        <item display-length="11" level="03" name="FS8" numeric="true" picture="S9(9)V99" position="54" scale="2" signed="true" storage-length="6" usage="computational-3"/>
        <item display-length="11" level="03" name="FS9" numeric="true" picture="S9(9)V99" position="60" scale="2" signed="true" storage-length="6" usage="computational-3"/>
        <item display-length="1" level="03" name="FS10" numeric="true" picture="9" position="66" storage-length="1"/>
        <item display-length="11" level="03" name="FS11" numeric="true" picture="S9(9)V99" position="67" scale="2" signed="true" storage-length="6" usage="computational-3"/>
        <item display-length="11" level="03" name="FS12" numeric="true" picture="S9(9)V99" position="73" scale="2" signed="true" storage-length="6" usage="computational-3"/>
        <item display-length="11" level="03" name="FS13" numeric="true" picture="S9(9)V99" position="79" scale="2" signed="true" storage-length="6" usage="computational-3"/>
        <item display-length="13" level="03" name="FS14-15" occurs="10" position="85" storage-length="13">
            <item display-length="1" level="05" name="FS14" numeric="true" picture="9" position="85" storage-length="1"/>
            <item display-length="11" level="05" name="FS15" numeric="true" picture="S9(9)V99" position="86" scale="2" signed="true" storage-length="6" usage="computational-3"/>
            <item display-length="11" level="05" name="FS16" numeric="true" picture="S9(9)V99" position="92" scale="2" signed="true" storage-length="6" usage="computational-3"/>
        </item>
        <item display-length="11" level="03" name="FS17" numeric="true" occurs="10" picture="S9(9)V99" position="215" scale="2" signed="true" storage-length="6" usage="computational-3"/>
        <item display-length="6" level="03" name="FS18" numeric="true" picture="9(6)" position="275" storage-length="6"/>
        <item display-length="1" level="03" name="FS19" numeric="true" picture="9" position="281" storage-length="1"/>
```

**List of all XML attributes**

I will be lazy here and just copy/paste my VB.NET code, there's a comment that explains clearly each attribute

```vb
      For Each Attribute As Xml.XmlAttribute In itemNode.Attributes

            Select Case Attribute.Name

                Case "name" ' FIeld name

                Case "level" ' PICTURE level

                Case "numeric"  ' True if numeric data type

                Case "picture" ' COmplete PICTURE string

                Case "storage-length" ' Variable storage lenght

                Case "usage" ' If COMP field, give the original COMP type ("computational-x")

                Case "signed" ' true if PIC S...

                Case "scale" ' Give number of digits afeter decimal point

                Case "redefined" ' true if the field is redifined afterwards

                Case "redefines" ' If REDEFINES : give the name of the redefined field

                Case "occurs" ' give the number of occurences if it's an ARRAY

                Case "position" ' Give the line position in the original copybook

                Case "display-length" ' Give the display size

                Case "filename" ' Give the FD name
```

With the help of this XML structure I have achieved all the goals and beyond.

The generated COBOL programs that convert the *indexed files* (readable only with RM cobol runtime) into *flat files* deals with every field, ARRAYS and REDEFINES included.

- For REDEFINES: I create a field for both the "primary" PICTURE, and all its REDEFINES alterations, and their type matches their COBOL PICTURE
- For ARRAYs, I create a field for each element, and also a huge field containing the whole array "line"
- For COMPUTATIONAL fields, I just move the original COMP into the exact same DISPLAY PICTURE

Not all the fields have a purpose when they are in the database but at least everything is available all the time

With the invoice file above, the SEQUENTIAL text file copybook becomes this :

### Auto generated COBOL

```
  FILE SECTION. 

  * ----------------------------------------------------------- 
  * INPUT FILE                                                
       COPY "FD8.COP" . 

  * -----------------------------------------------------------
  * OUTPUT FILE
   FD FACTURE-DWH.
   01 REC-FACTURE-DWH.      
       03 FS1-DWH           PIC X.
       03 FS2-DWH           PIC X(9).
       03 FS2A-DWH           PIC 9.
       03 RFS2B-DWH           PIC X(8).
       03 FS2B-DWH           PIC 9(8).
       03 FS3-DWH           PIC X(11).
       03 FS3A-DWH           PIC 9.
       03 FS3B-DWH           PIC X(10).
       03 FS4-DWH           PIC X(6).
       03 FS4A-DWH           PIC 99.
       03 FS4B-DWH           PIC 99.
       03 FS4C-DWH           PIC 99.
       03 FS5-DWH           PIC X(5).
       03 FS6-DWH           PIC X(20).
       03 FS7-DWH           PIC 9.
       03 FS8-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS9-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS10-DWH           PIC 9.
       03 FS11-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS12-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS13-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS14-15-1-DWH           PIC X(13).
       03 FS14-15-2-DWH           PIC X(13).
       03 FS14-15-3-DWH           PIC X(13).
       03 FS14-15-4-DWH           PIC X(13).
       03 FS14-15-5-DWH           PIC X(13).
       03 FS14-15-6-DWH           PIC X(13).
       03 FS14-15-7-DWH           PIC X(13).
       03 FS14-15-8-DWH           PIC X(13).
       03 FS14-15-9-DWH           PIC X(13).
       03 FS14-15-10-DWH           PIC X(13).
       03 FS14-1-DWH           PIC 9.
       03 FS14-2-DWH           PIC 9.
       03 FS14-3-DWH           PIC 9.
       03 FS14-4-DWH           PIC 9.
       03 FS14-5-DWH           PIC 9.
       03 FS14-6-DWH           PIC 9.
       03 FS14-7-DWH           PIC 9.
       03 FS14-8-DWH           PIC 9.
       03 FS14-9-DWH           PIC 9.
       03 FS14-10-DWH           PIC 9.
       03 FS15-1-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS15-2-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS15-3-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS15-4-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS15-5-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS15-6-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS15-7-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS15-8-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS15-9-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS15-10-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS16-1-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS16-2-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS16-3-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS16-4-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS16-5-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS16-6-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS16-7-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS16-8-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS16-9-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS16-10-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS17-1-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS17-2-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS17-3-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS17-4-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS17-5-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS17-6-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS17-7-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS17-8-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS17-9-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS17-10-DWH           PIC -9(9)V99.
       03 FS18-DWH           PIC 9(6).
       03 FS19-DWH           PIC 9.
```

**MOVE instructions**

```
  * ============================================================   
   PROG.                                                             
       MOVE FS1  TO FS1-DWH
       MOVE FS2  TO FS2-DWH
       MOVE FS2A  TO FS2A-DWH
       MOVE RFS2B  TO RFS2B-DWH
       MOVE FS2B  TO FS2B-DWH
       MOVE FS3  TO FS3-DWH
       MOVE FS3A  TO FS3A-DWH
       MOVE FS3B  TO FS3B-DWH
       MOVE FS4  TO FS4-DWH
       MOVE FS4A  TO FS4A-DWH
       MOVE FS4B  TO FS4B-DWH
       MOVE FS4C  TO FS4C-DWH
       MOVE FS5  TO FS5-DWH
       MOVE FS6  TO FS6-DWH
       MOVE FS7  TO FS7-DWH
       MOVE FS8  TO FS8-DWH
       MOVE FS9  TO FS9-DWH
       MOVE FS10  TO FS10-DWH
       MOVE FS11  TO FS11-DWH
       MOVE FS12  TO FS12-DWH
       MOVE FS13  TO FS13-DWH
       MOVE FS14-15(1)  TO FS14-15-1-DWH
       MOVE FS14-15(2)  TO FS14-15-2-DWH
       MOVE FS14-15(3)  TO FS14-15-3-DWH
       MOVE FS14-15(4)  TO FS14-15-4-DWH
       MOVE FS14-15(5)  TO FS14-15-5-DWH
       MOVE FS14-15(6)  TO FS14-15-6-DWH
       MOVE FS14-15(7)  TO FS14-15-7-DWH
       MOVE FS14-15(8)  TO FS14-15-8-DWH
       MOVE FS14-15(9)  TO FS14-15-9-DWH
       MOVE FS14-15(10)  TO FS14-15-10-DWH
       MOVE FS14(1)  TO FS14-1-DWH
       MOVE FS14(2)  TO FS14-2-DWH
       MOVE FS14(3)  TO FS14-3-DWH
       MOVE FS14(4)  TO FS14-4-DWH
       MOVE FS14(5)  TO FS14-5-DWH
       MOVE FS14(6)  TO FS14-6-DWH
       MOVE FS14(7)  TO FS14-7-DWH
       MOVE FS14(8)  TO FS14-8-DWH
       MOVE FS14(9)  TO FS14-9-DWH
       MOVE FS14(10)  TO FS14-10-DWH
       MOVE FS15(1)  TO FS15-1-DWH
       MOVE FS15(2)  TO FS15-2-DWH
       MOVE FS15(3)  TO FS15-3-DWH
       MOVE FS15(4)  TO FS15-4-DWH
       MOVE FS15(5)  TO FS15-5-DWH
       MOVE FS15(6)  TO FS15-6-DWH
       MOVE FS15(7)  TO FS15-7-DWH
       MOVE FS15(8)  TO FS15-8-DWH
       MOVE FS15(9)  TO FS15-9-DWH
       MOVE FS15(10)  TO FS15-10-DWH
       MOVE FS16(1)  TO FS16-1-DWH
       MOVE FS16(2)  TO FS16-2-DWH
       MOVE FS16(3)  TO FS16-3-DWH
       MOVE FS16(4)  TO FS16-4-DWH
       MOVE FS16(5)  TO FS16-5-DWH
       MOVE FS16(6)  TO FS16-6-DWH
       MOVE FS16(7)  TO FS16-7-DWH
       MOVE FS16(8)  TO FS16-8-DWH
       MOVE FS16(9)  TO FS16-9-DWH
       MOVE FS16(10)  TO FS16-10-DWH
       MOVE FS17(1)  TO FS17-1-DWH
       MOVE FS17(2)  TO FS17-2-DWH
       MOVE FS17(3)  TO FS17-3-DWH
       MOVE FS17(4)  TO FS17-4-DWH
       MOVE FS17(5)  TO FS17-5-DWH
       MOVE FS17(6)  TO FS17-6-DWH
       MOVE FS17(7)  TO FS17-7-DWH
       MOVE FS17(8)  TO FS17-8-DWH
       MOVE FS17(9)  TO FS17-9-DWH
       MOVE FS17(10)  TO FS17-10-DWH
       MOVE FS18  TO FS18-DWH
       MOVE FS19  TO FS19-DWH
```

Once the flat files are written, they can be processed to MySQL by the VBA code, also generated by the VB.NET application.

---

### Auto generated VBA

**Type def declaration** to deal with the text file importation

Note the original PICTURE in comments next to each field

```vb
'-------------------------------------------------------------
' REC_FC8 Record
'-------------------------------------------------------------
Private Type REC_FC8 
   FS1 as string*1  '  03 FS1  PIC X  
   FS2 as string*9  '  03 FS2  PIC   
   FS2A as string*1  '  05 FS2A  PIC 9  
   RFS2B as string*8  '  05 RFS2B  PIC X(8)  
   FS2B as string*8  '  05 FS2B  PIC 9(8)  
   FS3 as string*11  '  03 FS3  PIC   
   FS3A as string*1  '  05 FS3A  PIC 9  
   FS3B as string*10  '  05 FS3B  PIC X(10)  
   FS4 as string*6  '  03 FS4  PIC   
   FS4A as string*2  '  05 FS4A  PIC 99  
   FS4B as string*2  '  05 FS4B  PIC 99  
   FS4C as string*2  '  05 FS4C  PIC 99  
   FS5 as string*5  '  03 FS5  PIC X(5)  
   FS6 as string*20  '  03 FS6  PIC X(20)  
   FS7 as string*1  '  03 FS7  PIC 9  
   FS8 as string*12  '  03 FS8  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
   FS9 as string*12  '  03 FS9  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
   FS10 as string*1  '  03 FS10  PIC 9  
   FS11 as string*12  '  03 FS11  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
   FS12 as string*12  '  03 FS12  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
   FS13 as string*12  '  03 FS13  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
   FS14_15_1 as string*13  '  03 FS14-15  PIC   
   FS14_15_2 as string*13  '  03 FS14-15  PIC   
   FS14_15_3 as string*13  '  03 FS14-15  PIC   
   FS14_15_4 as string*13  '  03 FS14-15  PIC   
   FS14_15_5 as string*13  '  03 FS14-15  PIC   
   FS14_15_6 as string*13  '  03 FS14-15  PIC   
   FS14_15_7 as string*13  '  03 FS14-15  PIC   
   FS14_15_8 as string*13  '  03 FS14-15  PIC   
   FS14_15_9 as string*13  '  03 FS14-15  PIC   
   FS14_15_10 as string*13  '  03 FS14-15  PIC   
   FS14_1 as string*1  '  05 FS14  PIC 9  
   FS14_2 as string*1  '  05 FS14  PIC 9  
   FS14_3 as string*1  '  05 FS14  PIC 9  
   FS14_4 as string*1  '  05 FS14  PIC 9  
   FS14_5 as string*1  '  05 FS14  PIC 9  
   FS14_6 as string*1  '  05 FS14  PIC 9  
   FS14_7 as string*1  '  05 FS14  PIC 9  
   FS14_8 as string*1  '  05 FS14  PIC 9  
   FS14_9 as string*1  '  05 FS14  PIC 9  
   FS14_10 as string*1  '  05 FS14  PIC 9  
   FS15_1 as string*12  '  05 FS15  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
   FS15_2 as string*12  '  05 FS15  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
   FS15_3 as string*12  '  05 FS15  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
   FS15_4 as string*12  '  05 FS15  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
   FS15_5 as string*12  '  05 FS15  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
   FS15_6 as string*12  '  05 FS15  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
   FS15_7 as string*12  '  05 FS15  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
   FS15_8 as string*12  '  05 FS15  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
...
   FS17_8 as string*12  '  03 FS17  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
   FS17_9 as string*12  '  03 FS17  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
   FS17_10 as string*12  '  03 FS17  PIC S9(9)V99 computational-3 
   FS18 as string*6  '  03 FS18  PIC 9(6)  
   FS19 as string*1  '  03 FS19  PIC 9      
        FC8LF As String * 2 ' LF 11
End Type
```

**Create table procedure**

Each field has become an object (from a custom class I created), and the method `SQLtypeFull` used below returns the MySQL datatype of each field

```vb
'========================================================================
Private Function Create_Table_MySQL() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Erreur

    Dim Rs As Recordset
    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TBL_DAT_FACTURE` ( `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, `RECID` INT(11)"
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS1` " & FS1.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS2` " & FS2.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS2A` " & FS2A.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `RFS2B` " & RFS2B.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS2B` " & FS2B.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS3` " & FS3.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS3A` " & FS3A.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS3B` " & FS3B.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS4` " & FS4.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS4A` " & FS4A.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS4B` " & FS4B.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS4C` " & FS4C.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS5` " & FS5.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS6` " & FS6.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS7` " & FS7.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS8` " & FS8.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS9` " & FS9.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS10` " & FS10.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS11` " & FS11.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS12` " & FS12.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS13` " & FS13.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_15_1` " & FS14_15_1.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_15_2` " & FS14_15_2.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_15_3` " & FS14_15_3.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_15_4` " & FS14_15_4.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_15_5` " & FS14_15_5.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_15_6` " & FS14_15_6.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_15_7` " & FS14_15_7.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_15_8` " & FS14_15_8.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_15_9` " & FS14_15_9.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_15_10` " & FS14_15_10.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_1` " & FS14_1.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_2` " & FS14_2.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_3` " & FS14_3.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_4` " & FS14_4.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_5` " & FS14_5.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_6` " & FS14_6.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_7` " & FS14_7.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_8` " & FS14_8.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_9` " & FS14_9.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS14_10` " & FS14_10.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS15_1` " & FS15_1.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS15_2` " & FS15_2.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS15_3` " & FS15_3.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS15_4` " & FS15_4.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS15_5` " & FS15_5.SQLtypeFull
...
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS17_9` " & FS17_9.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS17_10` " & FS17_10.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS18` " & FS18.SQLtypeFull
           SQL = SQL &  ", `FS19` " & FS19.SQLtypeFull


    SQL = SQL & ", PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)"
    SQL = SQL & ") ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;"
    MySQLcon.Execute (SQL)      

    Create_Table_MySQL = True

Exit_Sub:
    Exit Function

Erreur:
    Create_Table_MySQL = False
    Resume Exit_Sub

End Function
```

Final SQL statement

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `FACTURE` 
( `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, `RECID` INT(11), `FS1` CHAR(1), `FS2` CHAR(9), `FS2A` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED, `RFS2B` CHAR(8), `FS2B` INT(8) UNSIGNED, `FS3` CHAR(11), `FS3A` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED, `FS3B` CHAR(10), `FS4` CHAR(6), `FS4A` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED, `FS4B` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED, `FS4C` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED, `FS5` CHAR(5), `FS6` CHAR(20), `FS7` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED, `FS8` DECIMAL(11,2), `FS9` DECIMAL(11,2), `FS10` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED, `FS11` DECIMAL(11,2), `FS12` DECIMAL(11,2), `FS13` DECIMAL(11,2), `FS14_15_1` CHAR(13), `FS14_15_2` CHAR(13), `FS14_15_3` CHAR(13), `FS14_15_4` CHAR(13), `FS14_15_5` CHAR(13), `FS14_15_6` CHAR(13), `FS14_15_7` CHAR(13), `FS14_15_8` CHAR(13), `FS14_15_9` CHAR(13), `FS14_15_10` CHAR(13), `FS14_1` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED, `FS14_2` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED, `FS14_3` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED, `FS14_4` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED, `FS14_5` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED, `FS14_6` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED, `FS14_7` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED, `FS14_8` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED, `FS14_9` TINYIN
T(1) UNSIGNED, `FS14_10` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED, `FS15_1` DECIMAL(11,2), `FS15_2` DECIMAL(11,2), `FS15_3` DECIMAL(11,2), `FS15_4` DECIMAL(11,2), `FS15_5` DECIMAL(11,2), `FS15_6` DECIMAL(11,2), `FS15_7` DECIMAL(11,2), `FS15_8` 
...
DECIMAL(11,2), `FS17_10` DECIMAL(11,2), `FS18` DATE, `FS19` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)) ENGINE=MyISAM  
 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

I have much more in the generated VBA modules, and the level of detail and accuracy of the generated xml helped a lot for all of them:

- I have created a Class that manage all aspects of fields, and notably take care of the conversions VBA/MySQL following the original PICTURE and VBA types (date, long, doubles, currency, etc...) and there's a hook in case you want to force another type.
- it deals entirely with the metadata creation (also in MySQL)
- it deals with the errors when importing data, logging everything at file and fields level

---

I have probably shown enough to give you some ideas so I will stop there.

**The most important:** When we transpose the complex computations made within the COBOL ERP, into SQL statements run against the new datawarehouse, the numbers returned by the DB are exactly identical to those into the ERP. On several millions of records, There's not a single digit loss on computations. This is the best way to prove that it works :-)

If you wonder why I used Access/VBA and not .NET for the importation: it was a non-negotiable requirement.

On a last note : I am not affiliated in any way with **CB2XML** and this is not an advertisement for it. It's just a great and helpful piece of software, which deserves some attention.

Comment: This worked amazingly on my home computer, but unfortunately i cannot install JDK on to my work computer...

Comment: @DanielDennis I don't know in which kind of company you are working, but frankly, for this kind of project, to get a development and production machine with Java shouldn't be an issue, or your company isnt serious.

Comment: I bugged them a little and i got it on there so we are all good now!

Comment: Once again Thank you very much!

Comment: Curious, When you had to deal with this did you have to read and convert variable length flat files as well? Or just fixed length.

Comment: ALL files are converted, for 2 reasons: Most of the files are only readable by the RM Cobol runtime (those not "flat"), and mostly all the files contains COMP / REDEFINES that should be moved (converted) into simple PIC 999 so they are exploitable by other systems

Answer (score 5):

`REDEFINES` is going to make your task more difficult. It is not the the "compiler" knows which particular field to use, intuitively, it is that the code in the existing COBOL system knows which field to use. There will be some indication, some value in another field, which will indicate which of the fields to use at which particular time.

Taking your second example, as the first is devoid of context:

```
05  ADDRESS-PO-BOX-FLAG                  PIC X.
```

That field will be interrogated before the data is used. Either directly (you can find lots of horrible code out there) or with an 88-level Condition Name:

```
    88  ADDRESS-IS-A-PO-BOX              VALUE "Y". (an example only)

IF ADDRESS-IS-A-PO-BOX
    some code relating to PO Boxes
ELSE
    some code relating to other types of addresses
END-IF
```

Your first example will be dealt with in a similar manner.

It is an "old style" use of REDEFINES, to use the same storage locations on a record for mutually-exclusive situations. Saves storage, which was expensive. The system you are working with is either "old", or the design of it was infected by false "experience".

You have two broad choices: to replicate all the conditional selection of data (so that you have two sets of business-logic to keep in step); to get the file changed so that each field occupies its own storage.

The presence of COMP-3 (or PACKED-DECIMAL) or COMP/COMP-4/COMP-5/BINARY data-types also complicate things for you. You'd need to then do your EBCDIC-to-ASCII at the field level, for actual EBCDIC data, and do whatever would be necessary to convert or simply acquire the "computational" data.

Also be aware that any signed-DISPLAY-numeric fields (numeric fields with a PICture beginning with an S but without an explicit "computational" usage) will apparently contain "character" data in the final byte, as the sign is held as an "overpunch" of the final byte.

Note that the binary data-types will be Big Endian.

It will be massively simpler for you if you receive files which have no REDEFINES, no "computational" fields, and no embedded signs (or implicit decimal-places). All your data would be character, and you can EBCDIC-to-ASCII at the record-level (or at the file level, with your file-transfer mechanism).

If you look at questions here tagged COMP-3, you'll find further discussion of this, and if you decide that the ridiculous route (your program understanding native Mainframe COBOL data-items rather than plain "text") is the only possible way to go, then there are a number of things in the discussions you may find useful and be able to use or apply.

If your company is "regulated" externally, then ensure your Compliance, Audit and Accounting departments are happy with your design before you code one line. Whoops. Late for that. Let's hope it is manufacturing.

Comment: First yes... the COBOL file i am dealing with is from 1988....... And it as sorta been updated, but more of patch work then a complete tear down.

Comment: As of right not my program reads in a cobol file and converts it to something that i can use and interpret easily (it displays this information and you can easily edit it). From there you upload a data file and convert on a record by record level (the computational fields were pretty easy to figure out as well as the occurs keyword). Once a packed number is converted the last character is C for positive and D for negative. The REDEFINES are the thing I can not figure out, My problems mainly come from a lack of knowing cobol and no mainframe experience

Comment: Also in terms of getting the file change.... unfortunately I am a very small pawn in a much bigger business dominated by legacy systems

Comment: '88 isn't that old :-) Somewhere in the COBOL system is "logic" which determines which of the fields directly and indirectly involved in the REDEFINES are used at what time. Please don't be blase about signs. A signed field *should* have a C or a D, but, particularly on poor systems, you may see an F, and even A, B and E are valid. Your life will be easy if you get textual data, with no REDEFINES. If it is a financial system, those people I mentioned have to be involved and they may well dictate (they have the power) that you are given that.

Comment: Yes it is a financial system, so I will at least try to get ahold of them, Thank you very much!