# Reading ISAM COBOL files using Pentaho DI

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, cobol, kettle, isam

We have multiple very old **ISAM COBOL** files on mainframe containing historical data. I have to build an ETL process to read/migrate this data (stored in the ISAM files) with Pentaho DI and load the same to PostgreSQL database with little or no transformations.

How do I achieve this with Pentaho DI ?

One workaround solution could be to write a Cobol program to convert the ISAM files to regular datasets in mainframe and then ftp/read the converted files easily. However, please let me know if there is a solution to read directly from the ISAM files with Pentaho without having to develop another cobol program. Also, please let me know any tips about the migration.

Comment: Do you really mean ISAM, or do you really mean VSAM? I doubt anyone would support anything with Mainframe ISAM files, they'd not expect anyone to still be using them 30+ years after VSAM existed,

Comment: One possible alternative is to find a JDBC driver for your files (whatever their type). On first look though, I only see commercial offerings.

Answer (score 3):

You are **not** going to be able to directly import ISAM (VSAM ???) files directly into Pentaho.

You do not need to write a program to unload an ISAM (VSAM ???) files,
**existing Mainframe** utilities (**sort** etc) can be used to do the unload. The unloaded file could then be transmitted to your system (it is probably going to be a **binary-ebcdic** file),
wether you can process the file is a different question.

---

#### Files:

**Complicated** files (e.g. have Cobol Redefines, Occurs Depending), are going to **require Cobol**.

For **simple** files:

- a **Mainframe-Sort** can convert the **Binary** files  to **Text**
  if needed.
- From memory Pentaho has some Cobol capabilities (based on cobol2j / cb2xml)
- there is a [legstar plugin](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Using+Pentaho+MapReduce+to+Parse+Mainframe+Data)
  for cobol processing.
- There is a Cobol-to-Csv programs in [JRecord](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord) that can be used
  convert Cobol files to CSV.

But:

- The files may not be sufficient, you may need other related details which could require additional Cobol extract programs.
- The Structure of the Current Tables are probably not ideal for your new purpose. Some times, it might be
  easier to do some transformation of the Mainframe because you have all the related Tables / DB's present on the Mainframe.

---

#### Things to watch out for

- Cobol **Redefines** - needs to be sorted out in Cobol on the Mainframe (or in Java~JRecord step). A Redefines clause is a major problem
  when Pic-x/9 fields redefine a binary (comp/comp-3) fields.
- **Occurs Depending On** - Fix in Cobol before transmission.
- **Multi-Record** files

---

#### Other approaches

- [Dynamically Reading COBOL Redefines with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846800/dynamically-reading-cobol-redefines-with-c-sharp/35977421#35977421)
  This is very similar project to yours (just different Cobol)
  where Thomas has generated the Cobol programs from the Copybook using [cb2xml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cb2xml).
  You could generate sorts.

**Disclosure:** I wrote JRecord and worked on cb2xml.

Comment: What a shame it was not accepted as an answer by the OP.

Comment: Thank you @PepitoSh the way it goes. Not may people use Cobol not many reads / upvotes. On the positive side there is not as much competition to answer questions