# Importing COBOL Data Into SQL

Tags: database, cobol

I am not even sure where to begin with this one. Our old accounting system used Cobol and flat files as a database. I was wondering if there was any way to import all of this into SQL and making it useful. Ideally I would like to get to a point where I could import this historical data into our ERP. The header in one of the files shows a RMKF entry and I also see some Cobol dll files on the server like Cob32api.dll
Any insight appreciated.

Comment: Directly importing?  Unlikely.  COBOL often used packed decimal and assumed decimal points neither of which make importing into SQL a walk in the park.  The file may also be indexed which you'd have to be able to understand to handle.  Not to mention the data may be encoded in EBCDIC and not ASCII.

Comment: Normally: get a COBOL programmer to write programs to unload the data

Answer (score 3):

Directly no. Any  answer will be determined on which **Cobol Dialect** you have (I would guess RM Cobol). Some of the Cobol compilers have there own `File System`. You may need to unload the files

In general while some Cobol files will be suitable for loading into a Database. Other will require programming:

- **Multi-Record** files - probably split in to several different tables
- Files with **redefines**

---

#### Accessing the data in the files

Loading the Files into a Database is either going to be expensive or time consuming (or both):

1. There are some commercial that provide access to Cobol Files (I would imagine they are expensive). Googling revealed: http://www.cobolproducts.com/datafile/data-viewer.html popup. But you will still need to **analyse** the files. Things like redefines can cause issues.
2. look at this answer [Dynamically Reading COBOL Redefines with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846800/dynamically-reading-cobol-redefines-with-c-sharp/35977421#35977421) It looks to be similar problem, Thomas used cb2xml to generate the Cobol.
3. If you get the files into a **Text format** (see 2 above), [cobolToCsv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltocsv/) may be useful - Csv files can generally be loaded in to Databases. cobolToCsv will not handle RM-Cobol files directly.

---

The [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) mentioned by Simon is unlikely to handle RM-Cobol binary files but should handle unloaded Text files. It may prove useful (note I am the author of the RecordEditor)

Comment: I suggest to add RecordEditor (found at SourceForge) to the list.

Comment: It seems like way more trouble than it would be worth. I will just run the old server until it dies.