# How to convert a Cobol copybooks into sql Server Create table statement...?

Tags: sql, ssis, cobol

I have to convert Cobol copybooks into Sql server create statement.

Sample CopyBook : [Click Here for sample Copybook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF378.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: on top of what @cschneid has said, post a text version of the copybook. Most people wont look at pictures of code or copybooks

Comment: What languages are you comfortable with ???

Comment: C# and ETL tool SSIS

Answer (score 1):

#### cb2xml

If you have a **lot** of copybooks to process, you could look at [cb2xml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cb2xml/). It can convert a *Cobol Copybook* to *Xml*. The cb2xml package has very basic examples of processing the Xml written in java / python / jython / ruby / Groovy. It is easier processing the Cobol in a JVM language.

Have a look at this question [Dynamically Reading COBOL Redefines with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846800/dynamically-reading-cobol-redefines-with-c-sharp/35977421) and the answer.

#### CobolToCsv

For **simple single-record** copybooks you could use [coboltocsv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltocsv/) to convert the Cobol file to Csv and process as a Csv file.

**Note:** I maintain **cb2xml** and **coboltocsv**