# Cobol Copybook Parser

Tags: parsing, cobol

Can anybody suggest me how to extract the fields of a Cobol Copybook?
It will be helpful if you could help with the code snippet or any links?
Example:

I want to extract it like this.

```
Field No.
Field Name
Field Type      (999 or S9(4) or x(5)....)
Field Type-add  (COMP, COMP-3, etc.,)
Other-Details   (Copy Everything until "." excluding PIC clause)
```

Comment: In general, this is a rather messy problem, since COBOL syntax is both expressive and ad hoc.  You don't mention important aspects of a COBOL data structure -- the group level hierarchy, REDEFINES, OCCURS, 77s, and 88s, etc.  Do you have a specific set of copybooks to work with?  And does this set use a subset of COBOL features?  You might be able to build something yourself.  Also, think about using a tool like `lex` to scan your copybooks to extract tokens.  `lex` will make it easier for you to distinguish periods from decimal points in numeric literals, e.g.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There are four hard problems in Computer Science: 1. Naming things; 2. Counting things; 3. Parsing COBOL.

Comment: There are numerous parsers available in many languages, but it definitely comes down to the question which language you can use to parse COBOL (flex/bison, GoldParser, Java, COBOL being some of the options) - but as cschneid already mentioned: please take the tour, this isn't a question for the Stackoverflow format.

Comment: @cschneid: Parsing COBOL is actually pretty easy compared to parsing C++.

Comment: @IraBaxter I never wrote compilers. I did have to write ISPF edit macros to help developers, so I used Rexx to "parse" COBOL to the extent needed to accomplish the task at hand.

Comment: Using REXX is tantamount to using regexes to parse context free languages.  It works only in very restricted circumstances.  Beyond that you need real parsiing machinery, or you will find many cases your tool cannot handle.  People never seem to learn this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I maintain [cb2xml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cb2xml/)

You could use [cb2xml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cb2xml/) to parse your copybooks

- In java each field is converted to a Cobol Object (with picture, usage, occurs fields)
- for Other languages the cobol can be converted to xml

See [Looking for The right way with Regular Expression with groups in different order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46750954/looking-for-the-right-way-with-regular-expression-with-groups-in-different-order/46762757#46762757)

Cobol:

```
   01 Ams-Vendor.
       03 Brand               Pic x(3).
       03 Location-details.
          05 Location-Number  Pic 9(4).
          05 Location-Type    Pic XX.
          05 Location-Name    Pic X(35).
       03 Address-Details.
          05 actual-address.
             10 Address-1     Pic X(40).
             10 Address-2     Pic X(40).
             10 Address-3     Pic X(35).
          05 Postcode         Pic 9(4).
          05 Empty            pic x(6).
          05 State            Pic XXX.
       03 Location-Active     Pic X.
```

Output from cb2xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<copybook filename="cbl2xml_Test110.cbl">
    <item display-length="173" level="01" name="Ams-Vendor" position="1" storage-length="173">
        <item display-length="3" level="03" name="Brand" picture="x(3)" position="1" storage-length="3"/>
        <item display-length="41" level="03" name="Location-details" position="4" storage-length="41">
            <item display-length="4" level="05" name="Location-Number" numeric="true" picture="9(4)" position="4" storage-length="4"/>
            <item display-length="2" level="05" name="Location-Type" picture="XX" position="8" storage-length="2"/>
            <item display-length="35" level="05" name="Location-Name" picture="X(35)" position="10" storage-length="35"/>
        </item>
        <item display-length="128" level="03" name="Address-Details" position="45" storage-length="128">
            <item display-length="115" level="05" name="actual-address" position="45" storage-length="115">
                <item display-length="40" level="10" name="Address-1" picture="X(40)" position="45" storage-length="40"/>
                <item display-length="40" level="10" name="Address-2" picture="X(40)" position="85" storage-length="40"/>
                <item display-length="35" level="10" name="Address-3" picture="X(35)" position="125" storage-length="35"/>
            </item>
            <item display-length="4" level="05" name="Postcode" numeric="true" picture="9(4)" position="160" storage-length="4"/>
            <item display-length="6" level="05" name="Empty" picture="x(6)" position="164" storage-length="6"/>
            <item display-length="3" level="05" name="State" picture="XXX" position="170" storage-length="3"/>
        </item>
        <item display-length="1" level="03" name="Location-Active" picture="X" position="173" storage-length="1"/>
    </item>
</copybook>
```

An interesting application of **cb2xml** is described in [Dynamically Reading COBOL Redefines with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846800/dynamically-reading-cobol-redefines-with-c-sharp/35977421#35977421)

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of ProLeap COBOL parser.

You could use the Java-based [ProLeap COBOL parser](https://github.com/uwol/proleap-cobol-parser) to extract all kinds of data from COBOL files such as [level numbers](https://github.com/uwol/proleap-cobol-parser/blob/f3c5497652183b318da73e2302da6d930b5bc5b8/src/test/java/io/proleap/cobol/asg/data/workingstorage/DataDescription01Test.java#L52), [picture strings](https://github.com/uwol/proleap-cobol-parser/blob/f3c5497652183b318da73e2302da6d930b5bc5b8/src/test/java/io/proleap/cobol/asg/data/workingstorage/DataDescriptionPictureTest.java#L36) etc. Also you can extract COMP, COMP-1 etc. from the usage clause [like this](https://github.com/uwol/proleap-cobol-parser/blob/f3c5497652183b318da73e2302da6d930b5bc5b8/src/test/java/io/proleap/cobol/asg/data/workingstorage/DataDescriptionClausesTest.java#L364).

The ProLeap COBOL parser is licensed under an open source license, so it can be used for free.

Answer (score 2):

For python, take a look at the Copybook package (https://github.com/zalmane/copybook). It supports most features of Copybook includes REDEFINES and OCCURS as well as a wide variety of PIC formats.

```
pip install copybook
root = copybook.parse_file('sample.cbl')
```

disclaimer : I am the maintainer of https://github.com/zalmane/copybook

Answer (score 0):

If you use a COBOL parser designed for the purpose, then this is relatively easy.

Such a parser has to be willing to parse not just
an entire program, but to parse various subparts, such as a copybook containing a paragraph or a data declaration.   Such a tool has to be prepared to
handle the complexities found in real copybooks, such as field declarations, PIC strings, REDEFINEs, 77 and 88 level variables, all manner of crazy literal values used as initializers, and the messy/ugly problems with line continuations and COPY REPLACING, or it will only handle vanilla copybooks.  Depending the origin of the copybook, you may have to process the text as EBCDIC.    Its actually a lot of work to build a parser that handles all of this.

If you try to hack it with regexes or something else that can't do something like context-free parsing, your resulting tool will simply not work on any complex cases.

A good parser will produce an abstract syntax tree capturing all these details as a data structure
in memory to be processed (this is efficient) or as an XML file to be
processed by some other tool.

Our [COBOL parser](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/COBOLFrontEnd.html?site=StackOverflow) for DMS can handle all of the above and generate an AST dump or an XML equivalent.

Given this COBOL copybook fragment:

```
003110****************************************
003120* GEGVD    - GEGVD-0872-WS
003130****************************************
003140 01  GEGVDC.
003150****************************************
003160****************************************
003170        10 GEJVD-CDA                            PIC X(11)
003180                                     VALUE
003190             '<<<GEGVD>>>'.
003200        10 GEJVD-COUNT                          PIC 9(9)
003210                                     VALUE     ZERO
003220                                     COMPUTATIONAL-3.
003230        10 GEJVD-ITER                           PIC 9(3)
003240                                     VALUE     ZERO
003250                                     COMPUTATIONAL-3.
003260        10 GEJVD-OP-CODE                        PIC X(1)
003270                                     VALUE     SPACE.
003280        10 GEJVD-STATUS                         PIC X(2)
003290                                     VALUE     SPACE.
003300        10 GEJVD-OPEN-SW                        PIC X(1)
003310                                     VALUE     SPACE.
003320        10 GEGVD-STATUS                         PIC X(2)
003330                                     VALUE     SPACE.
003340         10 STATUS-CODE REDEFINES
003350           GEGVD-STATUS                         PIC X(2).
003360 01  GEGVD.
003370****************************************
003380****************************************
003390     02 GEGVD-C.
003400        10 GEGVD-INPT-SCTN.
003410           15 GEGVD-ACTL-SERL-LN-CD             PIC X(1)
003420                                     VALUE     SPACE.
003430           15 GEGVD-FORM-VER-CD                 PIC X(5)
003440                                     VALUE     SPACE.
003450        10 GEGVD-OUTP-SCTN.
003460           15 GEGVD-GE-RULE-RSLT-CD             PIC X(1)
003470                                     VALUE     SPACE.
003480        10 GEGVD-WORK-SCTN.
003490           15 GEGVD-GE-RSN-00826-ID             PIC S9(5)
003500                                     VALUE     +00826
003510                                     COMPUTATIONAL-3.
003520           15 GEGVD-WS-N-LIT                    PIC X(1)
003530                                     VALUE     'N'.
003540           15 GEGVD-WS-S-LIT                    PIC X(1)
003550                                     VALUE     'S'.
003560           15 GEGVD-MPN-FORM-VER-CD             PIC X(5)
003570                                     VALUE     '99-00'.
003580           15 GEGVD-PLUS-MPN-FORM-VER-CD        PIC X(5)
003590                                     VALUE     '03-04'.
```

our  COBOL parser applied directly to the copybook file,
produces the following abstract syntax tree:

```
C:\DMS\Domains\COBOL\IBMEnterprise\Tools\Parser\Source>run ../domainparser ++AST c:/DMS/Domains/COBOL/IBMEnterprise/Examples/SallieMae/copylibs/GEGVD.COP
COBOL~IBMEnterprise Domain Parser Version 2.7.17
Copyright (C) 1996-2017 Semantic Designs, Inc; All Rights Reserved; SD Confidential
Powered by DMS (R) Software Reengineering Toolkit
AST Optimizations: remove constant tokens, remove unary productions, compact sequences
Using encoding Unicode-UTF-8?ANSI +CRLF +1 /^I
393 tree nodes in tree.
(cobol_source_file@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=17#92facc0^0 Line 4 Column 8
 (record_or_data_item_entry_list@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=721#92fac80^1#92facc0:1 Line 4 Column 8
  (record_01_description_entry@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=576#92f6240^1#92fac80:1 Line 4 Column 8
   (one@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2170#92f10e0^1#92f6240:1 Line 4 Column 8
   |(unsigned_integer_number@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2579#92f1080^1#92f10e0:1[1] Line 4 Column 8
   | precomment 0:1 Type 0 Line 1 Column 7 `****************************************'
   | precomment 0:2 Type 0 Line 2 Column 7 `* GEGVD    - GEGVD-0872-WS'
   | precomment 0:3 Type 0 Line 3 Column 7 `****************************************')unsigned_integer_number
   )one#92f10e0
   (data_description_entry@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=607#92f12c0^1#92f6240:2 Line 4 Column 12
   |(composed_identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2351#92f12a0^1#92f12c0:1 Line 4 Column 12
   | (identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2850#92f10c0^1#92f12a0:1[`GEGVDC'] Line 4 Column 12
   |)composed_identifier#92f12a0
   )data_description_entry#92f12c0
   ('.'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2358#92f1280^1#92f6240:3[Keyword:4] Line 4 Column 18
   (subsidiary_description_entry_list@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=585#92f61c0^1#92f6240:4 Line 7 Column 15
   |(subsidiary_description_entry@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=588#92f1800^1#92f61c0:1 Line 7 Column 15
   | (level_number@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2174#92f1360^1#92f1800:1 Line 7 Column 15
   |  (unsigned_integer_number@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2579#92f1320^1#92f1360:1[10] Line 7 Column 15
   |   precomment 0:1 Type 0 Line 5 Column 7 `****************************************'
   |   precomment 0:2 Type 0 Line 6 Column 7 `****************************************')unsigned_integer_number
   | )level_number#92f1360
   | (data_description_entry@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=608#92f1720^1#92f1800:2 Line 7 Column 18
   |  (composed_identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2351#92f13c0^1#92f1720:1 Line 7 Column 18
   |   (identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2850#92f1340^1#92f13c0:1[`GEJVD-CDA'] Line 7 Column 18
er
   |  )composed_identifier#92f13c0
   |  (data_description_clause_list@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=613#92f16e0^1#92f1720:2 Line 7 Column 55
   |   (picture_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=653#92f1520^1#92f16e0:1 Line 7 Column 55
   |   |(pic_picture@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=194#92f1420^1#92f1520:1 Line 7 Column 55
   |   | ('PIC'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2430#92f13a0^1#92f1420:1[Keyword:0] Line 7 Column 55
   |   |)pic_picture#92f1420
   |   |(optional_is@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=59#92f1440^1#92f1520:2 Line 7 Column 59
   |   |(picture_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=656#92f1500^1#92f1520:3 Line 7 Column 59
   |   | (alphanumeric_picture_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2543#92f1400^1#92f1500:1[`X(11)'] Line 7 Column 59
VD.COP)alphanumeric_picture_string
   |   |)picture_string#92f1500
   |   )picture_clause#92f1520
   |   (value_is_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=711#92f16a0^1#92f16e0:2 Line 8 Column 44
   |   |(value_values@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=202#92f1600^1#92f16a0:1 Line 8 Column 44
   |   | ('VALUE'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2437#92f14e0^1#92f1600:1[Keyword:0] Line 8 Column 44
   |   |)value_values#92f1600
   |   |(optional_is_are@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=63#92f1620^1#92f16a0:2 Line 9 Column 20
   |   |(non_figurative_non_numeric_literal@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2205#92f1680^1#92f16a0:3 Line 9 Column 20
COP
   |   | (non_numeric_literal_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2187#92f1660^1#92f1680:1 Line 9 Column 20
   |   |  (non_numeric_literal_quote@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2840#92f15e0^1#92f1660:1[`<<<GEGVD>>>'] Line 9 Column 20
s/GEGVD.COP)non_numeric_literal_quote
   |   | )non_numeric_literal_string#92f1660
   |   |)non_figurative_non_numeric_literal#92f1680
   |   )value_is_clause#92f16a0
   |  )data_description_clause_list#92f16e0
   | )data_description_entry#92f1720
   | ('.'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2358#92f1640^1#92f1800:3[Keyword:0] Line 9 Column 33
   |)subsidiary_description_entry#92f1800
   |(subsidiary_description_entry_list@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=585#92f6120^1#92f61c0:2 Line 10 Column 15
   | (subsidiary_description_entry@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=588#92f1c20^1#92f6120:1 Line 10 Column 15
   |  (level_number@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2174#92f18a0^1#92f1c20:1 Line 10 Column 15
   |   (unsigned_integer_number@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2579#92f17e0^1#92f18a0:1[10] Line 10 Column 15
igned_integer_number
   |  )level_number#92f18a0
   |  (data_description_entry@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=608#92f1bc0^1#92f1c20:2 Line 10 Column 18
   |   (composed_identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2351#92f18e0^1#92f1bc0:1 Line 10 Column 18
   |   |(identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2850#92f1820^1#92f18e0:1[`GEJVD-COUNT'] Line 10 Column 18
tifier
   |   )composed_identifier#92f18e0
   |   (data_description_clause_list@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=613#92f1ba0^1#92f1bc0:2 Line 10 Column 55
   |   |(data_description_clause_list@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=613#92f1aa0^1#92f1ba0:1 Line 10 Column 55
   |   | (picture_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=653#92f19a0^1#92f1aa0:1 Line 10 Column 55
   |   |  (pic_picture@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=194#92f1920^1#92f19a0:1 Line 10 Column 55
   |   |   ('PIC'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2430#92f18c0^1#92f1920:1[Keyword:0] Line 10 Column 55
   |   |  )pic_picture#92f1920
   |   |  (optional_is@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=59#92f1940^1#92f19a0:2 Line 10 Column 59
   |   |  (picture_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=655#92f1980^1#92f19a0:3 Line 10 Column 59
   |   |   (numeric_picture_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2542#92f1900^1#92f1980:1[`9(9)'] Line 10 Column 59
COP)numeric_picture_string
   |   |  )picture_string#92f1980
   |   | )picture_clause#92f19a0
   |   | (value_is_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=711#92f1a80^1#92f1aa0:2 Line 11 Column 44
   |   |  (value_values@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=202#92f1a00^1#92f1a80:1 Line 11 Column 44
   |   |   ('VALUE'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2437#92f1960^1#92f1a00:1[Keyword:0] Line 11 Column 44
   |   |  )value_values#92f1a00
   |   |  (optional_is_are@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=63#92f1a20^1#92f1a80:2 Line 11 Column 54
e
   |   |  (non_all_figurative_numeric_or_non_numeric_literal@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2203#92f1a60^1#92f1a80:3 Line 11 Column 54
ae/copylibs/GEGVD.COP
   |   |   ('ZERO'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2533#92f19e0^1#92f1a60:1[Keyword:0] Line 11 Column 54
   |   |  )non_all_figurative_numeric_or_non_numeric_literal#92f1a60
   |   | )value_is_clause#92f1a80
   |   |)data_description_clause_list#92f1aa0
   |   |(usage_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=684#92f1b80^1#92f1ba0:2 Line 12 Column 44
   |   | (optional_usage_is@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=674#92f1ae0^1#92f1b80:1 Line 12 Column 44
ge_is
   |   | ('COMPUTATIONAL-3'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2565#92f1a40^1#92f1b80:2[Keyword:0] Line 12 Column 44
'COMPUTATIONAL-3'
   |   |)usage_clause#92f1b80
   |   )data_description_clause_list#92f1ba0
   |  )data_description_entry#92f1bc0
   |  ('.'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2358#92f1b60^1#92f1c20:3[Keyword:0] Line 12 Column 59
   | )subsidiary_description_entry#92f1c20
   | (subsidiary_description_entry_list@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=585#92f5fe0^1#92f6120:2 Line 13 Column 15
   |  (subsidiary_description_entry@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=588#92f4120^1#92f5fe0:1 Line 13 Column 15
   |   (level_number@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2174#92f1d40^1#92f4120:1 Line 13 Column 15
   |   |(unsigned_integer_number@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2579#92f1be0^1#92f1d40:1[10] Line 13 Column 15
signed_integer_number
   |   )level_number#92f1d40
   |   (data_description_entry@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=608#92f40c0^1#92f4120:2 Line 13 Column 18
   |   |(composed_identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2351#92f1d80^1#92f40c0:1 Line 13 Column 18
   |   | (identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2850#92f1d00^1#92f1d80:1[`GEJVD-ITER'] Line 13 Column 18
tifier
   |   |)composed_identifier#92f1d80
   |   |(data_description_clause_list@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=613#92f40a0^1#92f40c0:2 Line 13 Column 55
   |   | (data_description_clause_list@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=613#92f1fa0^1#92f40a0:1 Line 13 Column 55
   |   |  (picture_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=653#92f1e40^1#92f1fa0:1 Line 13 Column 55
   |   |   (pic_picture@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=194#92f1dc0^1#92f1e40:1 Line 13 Column 55
   |   |   |('PIC'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2430#92f1d60^1#92f1dc0:1[Keyword:0] Line 13 Column 55
   |   |   )pic_picture#92f1dc0
   |   |   (optional_is@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=59#92f1de0^1#92f1e40:2 Line 13 Column 59
   |   |   (picture_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=655#92f1e20^1#92f1e40:3 Line 13 Column 59
   |   |   |(numeric_picture_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2542#92f1da0^1#92f1e20:1[`9(3)'] Line 13 Column 59
.COP)numeric_picture_string
   |   |   )picture_string#92f1e20
   |   |  )picture_clause#92f1e40
   |   |  (value_is_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=711#92f1f80^1#92f1fa0:2 Line 14 Column 44
   |   |   (value_values@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=202#92f1f00^1#92f1f80:1 Line 14 Column 44
   |   |   |('VALUE'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2437#92f1e00^1#92f1f00:1[Keyword:0] Line 14 Column 44

   |   |   )value_values#92f1f00
   |   |   (optional_is_are@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=63#92f1f20^1#92f1f80:2 Line 14 Column 54
re
   |   |   (non_all_figurative_numeric_or_non_numeric_literal@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2203#92f1f60^1#92f1f80:3 Line 14 Column 54
Mae/copylibs/GEGVD.COP
   |   |   |('ZERO'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2533#92f1ee0^1#92f1f60:1[Keyword:0] Line 14 Column 54
   |   |   )non_all_figurative_numeric_or_non_numeric_literal#92f1f60
   |   |  )value_is_clause#92f1f80
   |   | )data_description_clause_list#92f1fa0
   |   | (usage_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=684#92f4080^1#92f40a0:2 Line 15 Column 44
   |   |  (optional_usage_is@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=674#92f4000^1#92f4080:1 Line 15 Column 44
age_is
   |   |  ('COMPUTATIONAL-3'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2565#92f1f40^1#92f4080:2[Keyword:0] Line 15 Column 44
)'COMPUTATIONAL-3'
   |   | )usage_clause#92f4080
   |   |)data_description_clause_list#92f40a0
   |   )data_description_entry#92f40c0
   |   ('.'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2358#92f4060^1#92f4120:3[Keyword:0] Line 15 Column 59
   |  )subsidiary_description_entry#92f4120
   |  (subsidiary_description_entry_list@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=585#92f5e60^1#92f5fe0:2 Line 16 Column 15

   |   (subsidiary_description_entry@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=588#92f45c0^1#92f5e60:1 Line 16 Column 15
   |   |(level_number@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2174#92f4240^1#92f45c0:1 Line 16 Column 15
   |   | (unsigned_integer_number@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2579#92f40e0^1#92f4240:1[10] Line 16 Column 15
nsigned_integer_number
   |   |)level_number#92f4240
   |   |(data_description_entry@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=608#92f44e0^1#92f45c0:2 Line 16 Column 18
   |   | (composed_identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2351#92f4280^1#92f44e0:1 Line 16 Column 18
   |   |  (identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2850#92f4200^1#92f4280:1[`GEJVD-OP-CODE'] Line 16 Column 18
identifier
   |   | )composed_identifier#92f4280
   |   | (data_description_clause_list@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=613#92f44a0^1#92f44e0:2 Line 16 Column 55
   |   |  (picture_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=653#92f4340^1#92f44a0:1 Line 16 Column 55
   |   |   (pic_picture@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=194#92f42c0^1#92f4340:1 Line 16 Column 55
   |   |   |('PIC'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2430#92f4260^1#92f42c0:1[Keyword:0] Line 16 Column 55
   |   |   )pic_picture#92f42c0
   |   |   (optional_is@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=59#92f42e0^1#92f4340:2 Line 16 Column 59
   |   |   (picture_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=656#92f4320^1#92f4340:3 Line 16 Column 59
   |   |   |(alphanumeric_picture_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2543#92f42a0^1#92f4320:1[`X(1)'] Line 16 Column 59
GEGVD.COP)alphanumeric_picture_string
   |   |   )picture_string#92f4320
   |   |  )picture_clause#92f4340
   |   |  (value_is_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=711#92f4480^1#92f44a0:2
```

** middle of AST deleted due to size limitations on SO answers **

```
   |   |   (level_number@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2174#92f7140^1#92f7600:1 Line 44 Column 18
   |   |   |(unsigned_integer_number@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2579#92f6fa0^1#92f7140:1[15] Line 44 Column 18
P)unsigned_integer_number
   |   |   )level_number#92f7140
   |   |   (data_description_entry@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=608#92f7540^1#92f7600:2 Line 44 Column 21
   |   |   |(composed_identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2351#92f71a0^1#92f7540:1 Line 44 Column 21
   |   |   | (identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2850#92f70c0^1#92f71a0:1[`GEGVD-WS-S-LIT'] Line 44 Column 21
COP)identifier
   |   |   |)composed_identifier#92f71a0
   |   |   |(data_description_clause_list@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=613#92f74a0^1#92f7540:2 Line 44 Column 55
P
   |   |   | (picture_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=653#92f72c0^1#92f74a0:1 Line 44 Column 55
   |   |   |  (pic_picture@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=194#92f7220^1#92f72c0:1 Line 44 Column 55
   |   |   |   ('PIC'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2430#92f7160^1#92f7220:1[Keyword:0] Line 44 Column 55
   |   |   |  )pic_picture#92f7220
   |   |   |  (optional_is@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=59#92f7260^1#92f72c0:2 Line 44 Column 59
   |   |   |  (picture_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=656#92f72a0^1#92f72c0:3 Line 44 Column 59
   |   |   |   (alphanumeric_picture_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2543#92f7200^1#92f72a0:1[`X(1)'] Line 44 Column 59
bs/GEGVD.COP)alphanumeric_picture_string
   |   |   |  )picture_string#92f72a0
   |   |   | )picture_clause#92f72c0
   |   |   | (value_is_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=711#92f7460^1#92f74a0:2 Line 45 Column 44
   |   |   |  (value_values@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=202#92f7380^1#92f7460:1 Line 45 Column 44
   |   |   |   ('VALUE'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2437#92f7280^1#92f7380:1[Keyword:0] Line 45 Column 44
UE'
   |   |   |  )value_values#92f7380
   |   |   |  (optional_is_are@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=63#92f73a0^1#92f7460:2 Line 45 Column 54
s_are
   |   |   |  (non_figurative_non_numeric_literal@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2205#92f7440^1#92f7460:3 Line 45 Column 54
/GEGVD.COP
   |   |   |   (non_numeric_literal_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2187#92f7420^1#92f7440:1 Line 45 Column 54
COP
   |   |   |   |(non_numeric_literal_quote@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2840#92f7360^1#92f7420:1[`S'] Line 45 Column 54
EGVD.COP)non_numeric_literal_quote
   |   |   |   )non_numeric_literal_string#92f7420
   |   |   |  )non_figurative_non_numeric_literal#92f7440
   |   |   | )value_is_clause#92f7460
   |   |   |)data_description_clause_list#92f74a0
   |   |   )data_description_entry#92f7540
   |   |   ('.'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2358#92f73c0^1#92f7600:3[Keyword:0] Line 45 Column 57
   |   |  )subsidiary_description_entry#92f7600
   |   |  (subsidiary_description_entry_list@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=585#92fa180^1#92fa200:2 Line 46 Column 18
.COP
   |   |   (subsidiary_description_entry@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=588#92f7b40^1#92fa180:1 Line 46 Column 18

   |   |   |(level_number@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2174#92f7760^1#92f7b40:1 Line 46 Column 18
   |   |   | (unsigned_integer_number@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2579#92f75a0^1#92f7760:1[15] Line 46 Column 18
OP)unsigned_integer_number
   |   |   |)level_number#92f7760
   |   |   |(data_description_entry@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=608#92f7a60^1#92f7b40:2 Line 46 Column 21
   |   |   | (composed_identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2351#92f77c0^1#92f7a60:1 Line 46 Column 21
   |   |   |  (identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2850#92f7660^1#92f77c0:1[`GEGVD-MPN-FORM-VER-CD'] Line 46 Column 21
s/GEGVD.COP)identifier
   |   |   | )composed_identifier#92f77c0
   |   |   | (data_description_clause_list@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=613#92f7a20^1#92f7a60:2 Line 46 Column 55
OP
   |   |   |  (picture_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=653#92f7880^1#92f7a20:1 Line 46 Column 55
   |   |   |   (pic_picture@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=194#92f7800^1#92f7880:1 Line 46 Column 55
   |   |   |   |('PIC'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2430#92f77a0^1#92f7800:1[Keyword:0] Line 46 Column 55

   |   |   |   )pic_picture#92f7800
   |   |   |   (optional_is@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=59#92f7820^1#92f7880:2 Line 46 Column 59
   |   |   |   (picture_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=656#92f7860^1#92f7880:3 Line 46 Column 59
   |   |   |   |(alphanumeric_picture_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2543#92f77e0^1#92f7860:1[`X(5)'] Line 46 Column 59
ibs/GEGVD.COP)alphanumeric_picture_string
   |   |   |   )picture_string#92f7860
   |   |   |  )picture_clause#92f7880
   |   |   |  (value_is_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=711#92f79c0^1#92f7a20:2 Line 47 Column 44
   |   |   |   (value_values@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=202#92f7920^1#92f79c0:1 Line 47 Column 44
   |   |   |   |('VALUE'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2437#92f7840^1#92f7920:1[Keyword:0] Line 47 Column 44
LUE'
   |   |   |   )value_values#92f7920
   |   |   |   (optional_is_are@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=63#92f7940^1#92f79c0:2 Line 47 Column 54
is_are
   |   |   |   (non_figurative_non_numeric_literal@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2205#92f79a0^1#92f79c0:3 Line 47 Column 54
s/GEGVD.COP
   |   |   |   |(non_numeric_literal_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2187#92f7980^1#92f79a0:1 Line 47 Column 54
.COP
   |   |   |   | (non_numeric_literal_quote@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2840#92f7900^1#92f7980:1[`99-00'] Line 47 Column 54
ibs/GEGVD.COP)non_numeric_literal_quote
   |   |   |   |)non_numeric_literal_string#92f7980
   |   |   |   )non_figurative_non_numeric_literal#92f79a0
   |   |   |  )value_is_clause#92f79c0
   |   |   | )data_description_clause_list#92f7a20
   |   |   |)data_description_entry#92f7a60
   |   |   |('.'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2358#92f7960^1#92f7b40:3[Keyword:0] Line 47 Column 61
   |   |   )subsidiary_description_entry#92f7b40
   |   |   (subsidiary_description_entry@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=588#92fa0c0^1#92fa180:2 Line 48 Column 18

   |   |   |(level_number@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2174#92f7c80^1#92fa0c0:1 Line 48 Column 18
   |   |   | (unsigned_integer_number@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2579#92f7ae0^1#92f7c80:1[15] Line 48 Column 18
OP)unsigned_integer_number
   |   |   |)level_number#92f7c80
   |   |   |(data_description_entry@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=608#92f7fc0^1#92fa0c0:2 Line 48 Column 21
   |   |   | (composed_identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2351#92f7cc0^1#92f7fc0:1 Line 48 Column 21
   |   |   |  (identifier@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2850#92f7b60^1#92f7cc0:1[`GEGVD-PLUS-MPN-FORM-VER-CD'] Line 48 Column 21
pylibs/GEGVD.COP)identifier
   |   |   | )composed_identifier#92f7cc0
   |   |   | (data_description_clause_list@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=613#92f7f60^1#92f7fc0:2 Line 48 Column 55
OP
   |   |   |  (picture_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=653#92f7de0^1#92f7f60:1 Line 48 Column 55
   |   |   |   (pic_picture@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=194#92f7d20^1#92f7de0:1 Line 48 Column 55
   |   |   |   |('PIC'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2430#92f7ca0^1#92f7d20:1[Keyword:0] Line 48 Column 55

   |   |   |   )pic_picture#92f7d20
   |   |   |   (optional_is@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=59#92f7d40^1#92f7de0:2 Line 48 Column 59
   |   |   |   (picture_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=656#92f7da0^1#92f7de0:3 Line 48 Column 59
   |   |   |   |(alphanumeric_picture_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2543#92f7ce0^1#92f7da0:1[`X(5)'] Line 48 Column 59
ibs/GEGVD.COP)alphanumeric_picture_string
   |   |   |   )picture_string#92f7da0
   |   |   |  )picture_clause#92f7de0
   |   |   |  (value_is_clause@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=711#92f7f20^1#92f7f60:2 Line 49 Column 44
   |   |   |   (value_values@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=202#92f7e80^1#92f7f20:1 Line 49 Column 44
   |   |   |   |('VALUE'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2437#92f7d80^1#92f7e80:1[Keyword:0] Line 49 Column 44
LUE'
   |   |   |   )value_values#92f7e80
   |   |   |   (optional_is_are@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=63#92f7ea0^1#92f7f20:2 Line 49 Column 54
is_are
   |   |   |   (non_figurative_non_numeric_literal@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2205#92f7f00^1#92f7f20:3 Line 49 Column 54
s/GEGVD.COP
   |   |   |   |(non_numeric_literal_string@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2187#92f7ee0^1#92f7f00:1 Line 49 Column 54
.COP
   |   |   |   | (non_numeric_literal_quote@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2840#92f7e60^1#92f7ee0:1[`03-04'] Line 49 Column 54
ibs/GEGVD.COP)non_numeric_literal_quote
   |   |   |   |)non_numeric_literal_string#92f7ee0
   |   |   |   )non_figurative_non_numeric_literal#92f7f00
   |   |   |  )value_is_clause#92f7f20
   |   |   | )data_description_clause_list#92f7f60
   |   |   |)data_description_entry#92f7fc0
   |   |   |('.'@COBOL~IBMEnterprise=2358#92f7ec0^1#92fa0c0:3[Keyword:0] Line 49 Column 61
   |   |   )subsidiary_description_entry#92fa0c0
   |   |  )subsidiary_description_entry_list#92fa180
   |   | )subsidiary_description_entry_list#92fa200
   |   |)subsidiary_description_entry_list#92fa340
   |   )subsidiary_description_entry_list#92fa3c0
   |  )subsidiary_description_entry#92fa500
   | )subsidiary_description_entry_list#92fa6e0
   |)subsidiary_description_entry_list#92fa7a0
   )subsidiary_description_entry#92fa840
  )record_01_description_entry#92faac0
 )record_or_data_item_entry_list#92fac80
)cobol_source_file#92facc0

C:\DMS\Domains\COBOL\IBMEnterprise\Tools\Parser\Source>
```

Once you have the tree, it is fairly straightforward to walk over the tree and extract facts about the COBOL symbol declarations.

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer : I maintain https://www.cobolcopybook.co.in

Hi, check the site https://www.cobolcopybook.co.in, This site is designed specially for the analyze COBOL copybooks.

for Eg. Your input copybook is:

```
000100 01  BGG-FILE-REC.
000200     03  BGG-RCD-KEY.
000300         05  BGG-DUDENAME            PIC XXXX.
000400         05  BGG-DUDEADDR            PIC XX.
000500         05  BGG-HAIRCOLOR           PIC X(71).
000600         05  BGG-EYECOLOR            PIC X(8).
```

Then the output will be:

```
SR#  LEVEL   FIELD NAME                 PICTURE   TYPE      START      END   LENGTH

0  1  BGG-FILE-REC.                 @         AN            1       85       85
1  3  BGG-RCD-KEY.                  @         AN            1       85       85
2  5  BGG-DUDENAME                  XXXX.     AN            1        4        4
3  5  BGG-DUDEADDR                  XX.       AN            5        6        2
4  5  BGG-HAIRCOLOR                 X(71).    AN            7       77       71
5  5  BGG-EYECOLOR                  X(8).     AN           78       85        8
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: what happened to the web site you listed?  Did it move?  If so, what is the new URL?

Comment: Ah.  I was looking for Java code not an online thingy.  Also, popup reminders on **every** page are a last century thing & will quickly drive traffic away from your site.

Comment: @Roger Thank you for your messages. To keep running that site need fund but the popup is temporary and shortly will be removed. Thank you for visiting my site.

Comment: website unreachable

Comment: @Kharthigeyan Website is not up anymore.