# Solution for COBOL viewcall response string to java bean

Tags: java, spring, cobol

Currently I've a job to rewrite some library which communicate with COBOL Mainframe via ViewCall (Not sure if this is a universal term or not). The response will be a fixed length string according to the copybook. Are there any solutions or approach for Java to map this fixed length string to model class using copybook as a mapper instead of manually cut the strings and set it to model class?

Answer (score 1):

Some possible Solutions:

- For small Text Copybooks hand coding is feasible.
- next step up is to use [cb2xml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cb2xml/) and generate the code. Cb2xml will calculate position and length for you. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846800/dynamically-reading-cobol-redefines-with-c-sharp/35977421#35977421) shows what can be done with cb2xml.
- Use [JRecord ~ CodeGen](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/) to generate java classes. See [Generating Java Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313332/how-do-you-generate-javajrecord-code-for-a-cobol-copybook) for details on generating Java code. Java Jrecord is orientated to Files but should be usable.
  Remember there is a fair overhead in passing the Cobol copybook.

For a *one off* request with a small record, hand coding is viable option but you run the risk of subsequent requests coming along.

Comment: Hi, the last sentence of your answer is incomplete

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I cannot upvote the answer now but I'll try looking into JRecord.